# SPFx Single Sign On Redirect Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions

We have a simple SPFx Application Customizer which renders a global navigation to all sites.
We are using pnp to fetch items from a config list.
The component is running fine.
Each time we open a new browser-session or add a tab to the browser with a url of the tenant, the page is loading twice. We can see that the title "SPFx Single Sign On Redirect Page" is rendered on the tab when the page loads the second time.

[image]

What is causing the reload then?
This occures on a development tenant, logged-in in private mode.

Additional findings: This happens only on sub webs!
This does not occur, if we navigate from websitecontent to the sub-web (which also is adding a new tab to the browser).

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. Does any one has the solution? Thanks

Comment: Sorry to comment so old thread, but did you ever figure out what was causing this? We are now facing the same problem but without any modifications. It's vanilla modern communication site and we have a yammer (viva engage) conversations web part on the front page and it's causing the page to reload 2-3 times every time a new window/session is started.

Comment: @Tenttu The problem is related to third party cookies and the way SPFx web parts authenticate when required to load data from MS Graph or APIs secured by Entra ID. I validated this also happened to me when accessing a modern page from my iPhone with Intelligent Tracking Prevention enabled and a Viva Engage web part on it. You might find this article here interesting: https://www.blimped.nl/spfx-authentication-and-third-party-cookies/ and please note the update from February 2024.